# Global component with angular2

Tags: angular

Is it possible to add a component in the root component template and being able to access it from a child component. For example, imagine this is the root app component:

```
<main>
   <global-component #globalComponent></global-component>
   <child-component></child-component>
</main>
```

What I would like is, in the code of "child-component", being able to do something like this:

```
@Component({...})
export class ChildComponent
{
    @SomethingAwesome(GlobalComponent) globalComponent: GlobalComponent;
}
```

The goal is to be able to display errors/warning always in the same way. The "GlobalComponent" template would be a modal message and I want to be able to display it whenever I want. For example:

```
...
this.globalComponent.ShowError("Something's weird in here !");
...
```

The alternative (I guess) I have in mind is creating a service with an observable that "GlobalComponent" would subscribed to and react accordingly but I'm wondering if what I asked is possible.

Edit:

In the example, components are siblings but it might not always be the case. "GlobalComponent" should be available in any component, whatever its "deepness".

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are siblings, you can just pass it in

```ts
<main>
   <global-component #globalComponent></global-component>
   <child-component [global]="globalComponent"></child-component>
</main>
```

```ts
@Component({...})
export class ChildComponent
{
    @Input() global: GlobalComponent;

    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.global);
    }
}
```

Comment: They are siblings in my example but the goal is to be able to access "globalComponent" from any component. Sibling or not. Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: Then you need a shared service. The GlobalComponent can inject the shared service and register itself with the service and other components that access the same service can access `GlobalComponent` there. A better option is to have an `Observable` in the shared service and use that to communicate between components. One is the subscriber, the other the emitter.

Comment: See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Mmmmh, that's what I thought... Ok, I'll do it that way then. Thanks.

Comment: I just did it and it works. I marked the initial answer as accepted even though it's more the one in comment that solved my issue. Thanks