# Angular2 call a method on a child component from parent class

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript

**I would like to call a method on a child component from my parent's class**. I read about ViewChild or local variable, but my problem is that the child component is an external module.

My parent component is "carto.component", and it contains a "sebm-google-map" which is angular 2 module for google maps.

Currently, I call the method **triggerResize** like this :

```
<sebm-google-map #map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" (click)="map.triggerResize()">
```

To make my map re draw. I would like to call this method from the parent component which includes the map.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: I don't understand how this can help me

Comment: See the comments below my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021892/global-component-with-angular2/41021950#41021950

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try adding the view child reference to your 'carto.component'?

e.g.

```
@ViewChild('map') childMap: any;

onTrigger(){
  childMap.triggerResize();
}
```

Then in your template ...

`<sebm-google-map #map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" (click)="onTrigger()">`

If this is not what you are after, maybe you can clarify your question with an example.

Comment: I didn't understand very well ViewChild before, now it's better, thanks !